# Select a specific frame in a list where the objects are accessible by list[[i]]

Tags: r

I have a list in R where my objects are stored and accessible like this:

`list[[i]]`

If I have to select a specific zone of it, in a normal list I could just do `list[2:12]` for exemple.

But here, `list[[2]:[12]]` or `[[2:12]]`, nor `list[2:12]` is not working.

Which is the correct syntax? I'm a bit blocked.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: I can't, the list is gigantic. I can make an exemple though

Comment: Reduce it to the same structure. Or use `head` function

Comment: Okay , I'll try, found same more info here alseo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el?rq=1